# joomla facebook comments plugin error: cannot be crawled by Facebook's servers

Tags: facebook, joomla, facebook-apps

I installed AL Plugin Facebook Comments for Joomla 2.5/3.0 on my website. I add there Facebook App Id. But I am getting a warning: {website link} cannot be crawled by Facebook's servers. Why is that appear? Is there a way to remove it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is about Joomla extensions, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)